# SQL Server drivers not found by php.ini

Tags: php, apache, xampp, sqlsrv

I'm currently using XAMPP locally and I'm having problems while trying to make PHP recognize sqlsrv drivers (downloaded from
[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)).

I followed these steps:

1. installed the drivers
2. extracted them `to php/ext`
3. properly referenced them in `php.ini`
4. restarted apache

After that, I checked the `phpinfo.php` file and the only `PDO` Drivers listed are `mysql` and `sqlite`.

php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
```

Error log:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20200930\nPHP    compiled with module API=20210902\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20200930\nPHP    compiled with module API=20210902\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please double-check you're actually using a thread-safe x64 8.0 PHP setup. You'll also need the appropriate ODBC driver: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I've already found out the solution, thanks anyway.
There was no compatible SQL Server driver for PHP 8.1, so I had to use PHP 8.0 instead.